Flutter: No signature of method: java.util.Properties.getPdependenciesroperty()
After upgrading my AGP to 8.5.0 and kotlin to 1.9.24 and following this tutorial, I'm reciving this error when trying to build for Android inside Android/app/build.gradle:
 No signature of method: java.util.Properties.getPdependenciesroperty() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [flutter.versionName]

Here are my Android files:
Android/build.gradle


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



settings.gradle


pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.24" apply false
}

include ":app"



Android/app/build.gradle:


plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

// I copied these lines a long time ago, and not really sure if they should still exist, please forgive my ignorance
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

// these lines cause the error
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getPdependenciesroperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}



What should I do to fix this error?
Thanks!
